# Controller::edit(): Argument #1 ($id) must be of type int, string given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php8

Tengo un problema la verdad bastante extraño, estoy utilizando laravel tenancy y al momento de listar mis productos lo realiza sin ningun problema, pero al intentar acceder a un registro por medio de su id me arroja que estoy esperando un entero, pero recibio un string...

tengo en mi app mi controller de la siguiente forma.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Tenant\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\Tenant\CoOwnerFormRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\Tenant\CoOwnerResource;

use App\Traits\ApiResponder;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use App\Models\Tenant\CoOwner;

class CoOwnerController extends Controller
{
    
    
    public function index()
    {
        return CoOwnerResource::collection(
            CoOwner::filter(request()->only("search", "status"))
                ->orderBy('id')
                ->paginate(6)
        );
    }    

    public function edit(int $id)
    {
        $coowner = CoOwner::findOrFail($id);
        return new CoOwnerResource($coowner);
    } 
    
}
```

luego tengo mi modelo de esta forma

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Tenant;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Tenancy\Affects\Connections\Support\Traits\OnTenant;

/**
 * Transform the resource into an array.
 *
 * @package App\Models\Tenant
 * @property int $id
 */

class CoOwner extends Model
{
    use OnTenant, HasFactory, SoftDeletes;


    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public $timestamps= true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'correo',
        'telefono',
        'rut',
    ];


    //Relacion
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
     
}
```

Mi Resource.php de esta forma

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\Tenant;

use App\Models\Tenant\CoOwner;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class CoOwnerResource extends JsonResource
{    
    
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "user_id" => $this->user_id,   
            "correo" => $this->correo,
            "telefono" => $this->telefono,
            "rut" => $this->rut,
        ];
    }
    
}
```

y finalmente mi formRequest.php de esta forma

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Tenant;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CoOwnerFormRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        switch ($this->method()) {
            case "POST": {
                return [
                    "correo" => "required|max:140|unique:coowners",
                    "user_id" => "required|max:140",                    
                    "telefono" => "required|max:120",
                    "rut" => "required|max:120",
                ];
            }
            case "PUT": {
                return [                   
                   otro codigo
                ];
            }
            default: {
                return [];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

y finalmente parte de mi ruta donde tengo configurado para acceder al edit esta asi.

```
 Route::get("/coowners/index", [CoOwnerController::class, "index"]);
 Route::get("/coowners/{id}/edit", [CoOwnerController::class, "edit"]);
```

Aqui al listar la informacion no tengo problemas, me trae los registros, pero al momento de intentar editar y al momento de enviar un id por la url
http://127.0.0.1:8000/tenancycliente/api/coowners/1/edit
me arroja como error:

```
message": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\Tenant\\Api\\CoOwnerController::edit(): Argument #1 ($id) must be of type int, string given, called in C:\\DEV C\\backendc\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php on line 54",
    "exception": "TypeError",
    "file": "C:\\DEV C\\backendc\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Tenant\\Api\\CoOwnerController.php",
    "line": 37,
```

Detallo gran parte del codigo y a su vez el error para entregar la mayor cantidad de detalles para exponer lo mas claro el problema, por otra parte en mi base de datos al crear la migracion, de manera automatica este id queda como bigint.

espero se entienda el problema, que aunque parece ser basico me tiene bien enredado porque no logro pillar la solucion, nunca me habia pasado.

Utilizo Laravel 8 y php 8.0

Comment: Que pasa si no declaras el tipo? `edit($id)`. O si usas model binding `edit(CoOwner $id)`?

Comment: hice lo de dejar  ```edit($id)``` y me dice Argument #1 ($id) must be of type int, string given, en ningun lado estoy pasando un string y al usar  ```edit(CoOwner $id)``` me dice Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. 
Esta muy raro, nunca habia obtenido este error, sin embargo para listar no tengo problema alguno...